# Download of large blob from Azure Blob Storage was frozen

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We use Azure Blob Storage as a storage for large files (~5-20Gb)
Our customer reported about problem. Download of such files sometimes stops and never ends.
I have logged download statistics and tried to download problem file several times. One of the attempt was unsuccessful and now I have a chart downloaded_size/time:[image: chart]

There were short pauses in downloading from 16:00 to 16:12. Intervals between pauses are identical, but length raises. At 16:12 speed become Kb/s and never returned to normal values.

Here is a code that proceed downloading (.NET 4.0):

```
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(containerSAS));

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        var options = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            ServerTimeout = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0, 0),
            RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), 100),
        };

        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(outputStream, null, options);
```

What could be a reason of such problems?

**EDIT** To get statistics I used the following Stream implementation:

```
public class TestControlledFileStream : Stream
{
    private StreamWriter _Writer;
    private long _Size;

    public TestControlledFileStream(string filename)
    {
        this._Writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _Size += count;
        _Writer.WriteLine("{0}: ({1}, {2})", DateTime.UtcNow, _Size, count);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this._Writer != null)
            this._Writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are having issues downloading a large blob. I have provided some steps below to help you debug these kinds of issues.

*Quick comment*: You don’t need to specify the linear retry policy for this download. The default exponential retry policy should suffice for your scenario. By setting the number of allowed failures for this retry policy to 100 you may be prolonging a problem that retrying won’t fix. Is there a reason you chose to use linear retry?

**Debugging Azure Storage Issues**

- Storage Analytics logs are a useful first step in debugging as they
  give you information about your requests such as server latency or
  response status code. You can check what info is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343259.aspx) 
  and learn how to use logging [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/10/storage-analytics-logging-how-to-enable-and-where-to-find-the-logs.aspx).
- [Client-side logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782839.aspx)
  provides client specific information that can help you narrow down
  your issue.
- Using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on your client can provide visibility for the state of your download such as if the client is retrying or not. Note that this may obfuscate speed or connection issues as the traffic will run the traffic through a proxy.

If you get more detailed information regarding this issue, we will be able to help mitigate your issue.